# How to use AngularJS built-in directives with custom input directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, selectize.js

I am trying to write a directive to wrap the Selectize jQuery plugin.  I have it mostly functional, but I need to handle validations for required and maxlength.  I am trying to make use of the ng-required and ng-maxlength directives, but can't get either to work.  I also couldn't get the HTML maxlength attribute to work.  Should I be able to use built-in Angular directives on top of my directive, or will I need to check and set the validity myself?

Here is my directive code:

```
.directive('selectize', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs, ngModel ) {
            var options = scope.$eval(attrs.options);
            var formattedOptions = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var option = options[i];
                formattedOptions.push( { 'value': option, 'label': option } );
            }

            element.selectize({
                options: formattedOptions,
                labelField: 'label',
                valueField: 'value',
                sortField: 'value',
                searchField: 'value',
                maxItems: 1,
                hideSelected: true,
                persist: false,
                render: {
                    option_create: function ( data, escape ) {
                        return '<div class="create">' + data.input + '</div>';
                    }
                }
            });

            element.on( 'change', function () {
                scope.$apply( function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue( element.val() );
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

And HTML:

```
<input selectize 
       options="field.options"
       ng-model="field.response"
       class="form-control"
       ng-required="field.required">
</input>
```

When I inspect this element, required is set to false even though the value of field.required is true.  Similarly, when I tried to use ng-maxlength it did not display any validation errors (ng-maxlength and validation error HTML not shown).  Using the HTML maxlength attribute did not restrict the number of characters I attempted to enter either.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I'm new to directives, so if there are any other best practices I'm missing feel free to point those out as well.  Thanks!

Comment: likely has more to do with the plugin than your code. You probably need to work within the plugin API events for your validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the Angular docs on [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and following the Custom Control example I discovered I wasn't using ngModel correctly in my directive.  After making the following changes I was able to use ng-required along with my custom directive.

1 - I changed `require: ngModel` to `require: ?ngModel`

2 - I added the following to handle the selectize input not retaining the value stored in ngModel:

```
var selectize = element[0].selectize;
ngModel.$render = function() {
    selectize.setValue( ngModel.$viewValue );
}
```

3 - To resolve errors about digest already being in progress, I modified my element on change to use $timeout:

```
element.on( 'change', function () {
    $timeout( function() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue( element.val() );
    });
});
```